# Why does Tensorflow dataset generation shuffle data twice?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking at the timeseries_dataset_from_array function in TensorFlow, it can be found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3d3552f218b920e3d9011dbe7017d996ae8e63b2/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/timeseries.py

In the function's logic, it can be clearly seen that there are two shuffles happening. First on line 195, when generating start positions for the sliding windows, then on line 222, before batching. It also has a comment: "Shuffle locally at each iteration". And I don't understand - which iterations these are or how the model benefits from the second shuffle.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning or deep learning, it is always based on the assumption that data is independent and identically distribution, the order of data should be random.

There are usually multiple iterations in a model training task. Shuffled data in each iteration would improve generalization performance of the model.

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.data.ops import dataset_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops


def timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data,
        sequence_length,
        sequence_stride=1,
        sampling_rate=1,
        batch_size=128,
        shuffle=False,
        seed=None,
        start_index=None,
        end_index=None):
    
    if start_index is None:
        start_index = 0
    if end_index is None:
        end_index = len(data)

    # Determine the lowest dtype to store start positions (to lower memory usage).
    num_seqs = end_index - start_index - (sequence_length * sampling_rate) + 1
    if num_seqs < 2147483647:
        index_dtype = 'int32'
    else:
        index_dtype = 'int64'

    # Generate start positions
    start_positions = np.arange(0, num_seqs, sequence_stride, dtype=index_dtype)
    if shuffle:
        if seed is None:
            seed = np.random.randint(1e6)
        rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)
        rng.shuffle(start_positions)

    sequence_length = math_ops.cast(sequence_length, dtype=index_dtype)
    sampling_rate = math_ops.cast(sampling_rate, dtype=index_dtype)

    positions_ds = dataset_ops.Dataset.from_tensors(start_positions).repeat()

    # For each initial window position, generates indices of the window elements
    indices = dataset_ops.Dataset.zip(
        (dataset_ops.Dataset.range(len(start_positions)), positions_ds)).map(
        lambda i, positions: math_ops.range(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
            positions[i],
            positions[i] + sequence_length * sampling_rate,
            sampling_rate),
        num_parallel_calls=dataset_ops.AUTOTUNE)

    dataset = sequences_from_indices(data, indices, start_index, end_index)
    if shuffle:
        # Shuffle locally at each iteration
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=batch_size * 8, seed=seed)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset


def sequences_from_indices(array, indices_ds, start_index, end_index):
    dataset = dataset_ops.Dataset.from_tensors(array[start_index: end_index])
    dataset = dataset_ops.Dataset.zip((dataset.repeat(), indices_ds)).map(
        lambda steps, inds: array_ops.gather(steps, inds),  # pylint: disable=unnecessary-lambda
        num_parallel_calls=dataset_ops.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset


X = np.arange(12)

input_dataset = timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    X, sequence_length=3, sequence_stride=3, shuffle=True, batch_size=2)

for i in range(3):
    print("--------------iteration", i)
    for inputs in input_dataset:
        print(inputs)
```

**Outputs**:

> --------------iteration 0
>
> tf.Tensor( [[ 6  7  8]  [ 9 10 11]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
> tf.Tensor( [[3 4 5]  [0 1 2]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
>
> --------------iteration 1
>
> tf.Tensor( [[3 4 5]  [6 7 8]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
> tf.Tensor( [[ 0  1  2]  [ 9 10 11]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
>
> --------------iteration 2
>
> tf.Tensor( [[6 7 8]  [0 1 2]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
> tf.Tensor( [[ 3  4  5]  [ 9 10 11]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)

When the `shuffle` is true, result of each iteration in the dataset is different, and it is caused by the second shuffle.